# What's the easiest way to make Text follow the curve of a Circle shape in KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, text, path, kineticjs

Is there no other way then to use TextPath with a SVG string as data/input? If so my options seem to be:

- Create a circle in Inkscape and copy the SVG string.
- Learn some part of SVG and manually write a circle SVG string.
- Learn some part of SVG and create a function that automatically generates circle SVG strings based on radius input.

The last one seems the best, but is it not possible to use a KineticJS Circle Shape as input somehow? Seems ideal, and it would also allow me in the future to make text follow the stroke of other kinds of shapes like Rect or Polygon.

So basically, is there any better way to make text follow a circle path in KineticJS other then to use SVG?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the textPath plugin for KineticJS here:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/plugins/TextPath.js